# defining json post parameters in apiary

Tags: apiblueprint, apiary.io, apiary

I'm trying to create documentation for a project using json post requests.
Now for get requests I can easily define uri parameters.

However I want to do the same for json and other post requests.
I tried and wished it would work something like below, it displays the parameters in the example but it doesn't seem to be the way to do it...
Is there a way to do this properly?

```
## Post Inbound [/ws/3/inbound]
### Post Inbound [POST]


+ Request

        {
            "authentication":
                {
                    "location":"{location}",
                    "customer_id":{customer_id},
                    "context":"{context}"
                },
            "date":"",
            "reference":"",
            "details":
            [
                {
                    "article_code":"",
                    "qty_expected":
                },
                {
                    "article_code":"",
                    "qty_expected":
                }
            ]
        }

+ Parameters
    + location (required, string) - Target url of the wics server 
    + customer_id (required, int) - Customer ID
    + context (required, string) - Authentication context gotten from login
    + date (required, date) - Date format as yyyy-mm-dd
    + reference (required, string) - Reference
    + article_code (required, string) - Article code
    + qty_expected (required, int) - Quantity expected.
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `Parameters` keyword is to indicate [URI parameters](https://github.com/apiaryio/api-blueprint/blob/master/API%20Blueprint%20Specification.md#def-uriparameters-section) in API Blueprint, whereas the [Attributes](https://github.com/apiaryio/api-blueprint/blob/master/API%20Blueprint%20Specification.md#def-attributes-section) keyword is to indicate attributes such as those given during a request or response body.

This would look something like the following for your request:

```
## Post Inbound [/ws/3/inbound]
### Post Inbound [POST]

+ Request (application/json)

    + Attributes
        + authentication (required, object)
            + location (required, string) - Target url of the wics server 
            + customer_id (required, number) - Customer ID
            + context (required, string) - Authentication context gotten from login
        + date: `2015-12-30` (required, string) - Date format as yyyy-mm-dd
        + reference (required, string) - Reference
        + details (required, array)
            + (object)
                + article_code (required, string) - Article code
                + qty_expected (required, number) - Quantity expected.

+ Response 204
```

And rendered as such in Apiary:

[image: MSON expanded and rendered at Apiary]

The full specification for the MSON (the syntax for object notation used in API Blueprint) can be found at https://github.com/apiaryio/mson.